# Problem with Greek letters in mathptmx

Tags: math-mode, postscript, mathptmx

I'm new to Latex and I'm supposed to write a journal paper using the template provided by the journal itself. The guides in the template suggest using PostScript fonts by the package "mathptmx".

1. I can't produce uppercase Greek letters in math formulas, I tried "\upOmega" (got from http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf) but it gives a simple vertical line "|".
2. Is it possible to generate script letters when using this package?

Sorry if there are technical errors in my question, I'm just new to Latex and I'm really confused.

**Example:**

In the preamble: `\usepackage{mathptmx}`

```
\begin{equation}
\upOmega+b^2=C^2
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\Omega` should work.

Comment: Thanks egreg! No it doesn't! It gives "\" in the formula.

Comment: Please, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the issue.

Comment: I just noticed that the problem is with the TeXstudio's PDF viewer! I used Adobe Reader and everything is OK!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has turned out, that this is a rendering problem.